# How to write and read component state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have MyComponent using setData() to write data in state and getData() to read the state. Is it best practice in React ? It works fine for me but not sure if what I am doing is the simplest possible way, please advice

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };

  }

  setData(){    
    this.setState({data:"123"});   
  }

  getData() {
    console.log(this.state.data); // 123 OK !!!   
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.setData();  

  }
  componentDidUpdate() { 
    this.getData();
  }
  render() {
    return (                     
       <div>           
          {this.state.data} // 123 OK !!!
       </div>                        
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case setData() is i.e. getLocation() which reads current location, and I am using it in getWeather() which takes location (my getData()) and gets the local weather for the current location. So is doing it thru state not necessary, what's the simpler way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to do this.
Just use `this.state.data` wherever you need to use it.

If you want to use the state data in a child component, then pass it as a prop and you may also pass a function to the child component that changes the state of the parent component.

([source](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html))

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to change the data as some component then you must use setState .
2. If you want to get the data then you must use this.state.data where data is state variable .
3. if you want to pass data from parent to child component by using pros.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, please try to directly answer the OPs question. Especially on opinion based question, make sure to always provide reasons for your recommended actions to the OP (e.g. official guidelines or docs)